# meaning of "Don't take questions"

Tags: meaning

Jen PSaky said :

> Don't take questions

in White House press secretary frowns on Biden's media interaction.

What's the meaning of this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of every press conference, there is usually a question section when journalists ask questions and speakers try to answer them. When you take a question, you invite it, you listen to it, and you respond to it.